# I downloaded my website files using filezilla from remote site to edit. But I can't locate it on my machine.

Tags: laravel, hosting, filezilla

I had a few bugs in my code for a website and i need to download all the files of the website to my development machine for editing. I did so in Filezila by clicking on the root folder on the remote site and took the download option. It finished downloading but i couldn't locate it on the local machine.
I know my question may be stupid but please help cuz i am new to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the bottom of the filezilla you have three tabs after the console log that is 1) Queued files 2) Failed transfer 3) Successful transfers

Again download the file and after download has complete click on Successful transfers option and there you would find the log and path where your files are downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your download path appears here:
[image]